# Xcode and Instruments tracking memory usage

Tags: debugging, xcode4, memory-leaks, instruments, valgrind

My app on iOS simulator is using way too much memory. It's probably that memory is leaking. It's a ARC-enabled project with incorporation of plain C code. I tried it with some small project which I malloc and leak on purpose, instrument does not seem to notice. I tried it using Valgrind as described  [here](http://root42.blogspot.tw/2011/02/valgrind-checking-of-ios-programs.html), but I just can't get it to run. It says "error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file".

What other options do I have? Any suggestions to how I would find what I'm leaking?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest beta release of Xcode?  finding memory issues has ben greatly improved.  There is now a display of memory usage when debugging and you can click on that and dive into the code in a way that is more intuitive than using instruments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to late but you can use Valgrid... http://valgrind.org/ ?